# Compress Javascript in Windows

Tags: yui, yui-compressor

Does anyone know any good links on how to minify/compress javascript files using YUI Compressor in Windows? I am trying to figure out how to get it installed, then compress javascript using the msdos command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Install [Nodejs for Windows](http://nodejs.org/download/)
2. [npm (node package manager) comes with the MSI you just grabbed and installed](https://npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Super-Easy-Install)
3. Run `npm install yuicompressor`
4. Read the [docs](https://npmjs.org/package/yuicompressor) and compress files

I would recommend [uglify-js](https://npmjs.org/package/uglify-js) over YUI Compressor since [it is in a deprecation process](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2012/10/16/state-of-yui-compressor/). Same install as above.

Comment: Before you responded, I managed to get it working. I just downloaded the yui jar file from github, then run java -jar yui.jar etc... Does this sound ok or should I do it the way you stated?

Comment: Choose whatever works for you. There are benefits using Node.js as the environment for things like these.

Also, YUI Compressor has been, allegedly, abandoned by YUI. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use gruntjs with [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify).